# In which Batman comic does Robin touch a mirror to discover himself?

Tags: dc, episode-identification, robin

Batman is in trouble from the Joker, and a large yellow beast. Robin, just a boy at the time, touches a liquid mirror (like in the matrix when Neo touches one), becoming an adult-ish Robin, no longer just an ordinary boy.

It's from the 80s/early 90s as far as I can remember. Maybe even a different continuity from the standard DC Batman.

Also, i remember it was from one of those types of issues, where batman had long ears and was very 
dracula-like (such as seen in the issues of 400-500s).

EDIT:
The comic itself had many advertisements, the first page had a Chuck Norris type guy shattering a brick wall by kicking on the first few pages.

Comment: "becoming Robin, from the boy."  This made my head hurt.  He became _adult_ Robin?

Comment: adult-ish, not some 10 year old kid

Comment: That style of Bat was [Kelley Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelley_Jones), but nothing on the list on that page jumps out. Nor could I find a reference to Robin.

Comment: do you remember if it was Dick Grayson or Jason Todd?

Comment: he was pretty young now that i think about it, so maybe Dick Grayson, also batman's car was like the one from the 80s movies, except higher (SUV like) and not as long

Comment: @heyNow: "the one from the 80s movies" - this from Pedant's Corner, there was only [one Batman movie from the 80s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(1989_film)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally found it after a year and half of searching. It's [Detective Comics #623](http://www.comicvine.com/detective-comics-623-death-of-innocence/4000-113082/).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Could you be referring to [World's Finest #121](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_121), "The Mirror Batman"?

- Robin, Superman and Batman travels through a mirror and become distorted
- Batman's distortions make him looks like an animal
- Our heroes fight a yellow monster creature called Xanu

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no, this isn't the one. This is far too comical, that one was pretty serious. Theoretically, your answer does have all the criteria.  
My comic book could have just been created by an ardent fan, but it was an amazing work, I was too young to understand its value at the time